# Keeping number of hits in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of (unique) words:

```
words = [store, worry, periodic, bucket, keen, vanish, bear, transport, pull, tame, rings, classy, humorous, tacit, healthy]
```

That i want to crosscheck with two different lists of lists (with the same range), while counting the number of hits.

```
l1 = [[terrible, worry, not], [healthy], [fish, case, bag]]
l2 = [[vanish, healthy, dog], [plant], [waves, healthy, bucket]]
```

I was thinking of using a dictionary and assume the word as the key, but would need two 'values' (one for each list) for the number of hits.
So the output would be something like:

```
{"store": [0, 0]}
{"worry": [1, 0]}
...
{"healthy": [1, 2]}
```

How would something like this work?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you've got the basic structure worked out. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Make your life easier and use a list of `collections.Counter` instead?

Comment: @glibdud, i think i have the idea right, but i might be missing some kind of method or workaround that could be simpler than iterating and adding... like what tobias said right now... going to check that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools to flatten the list and then use dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain
words = [store, worry, periodic, bucket, keen, vanish, bear, transport, pull, tame, rings, classy, humorous, tacit, healthy]

l1 = [[terrible, worry, not], [healthy], [fish, case, bag]]
l2 = [[vanish, healthy, dog], [plant], [waves, healthy, bucket]]

l1 = list(chain(*l1))

l2 = list(chain(*l2))

final_count = {i:[l1.count(i), l2.count(i)] for i in words}
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax, also works perfectly. Short and elegant. That chain will also come very handy to simplify some of my previous code!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

For your dictionary example, you would just need to iterate over each list and add those to the dictionary as so:

```
my_dict = {}
for word in l1:
    if word in words: #This makes sure you only work with words that are in your list of unique words
        if word not in my_dict:
            my_dict[word] = [0,0]
        my_dict[word][0] += 1
for word in l2:
    if word in words:
        if word not in my_dict:
            my_dict[word] = [0,0]
        my_dict[word][1] += 1
```

(Or you could make that repeated code a function that passes in for parameter the list, dictionary, and the index, that way you repeat fewer lines)

If your lists are 2d like in your example, then you just change the first iteration in the for loop to be 2d.

```
my_dict = {}
for group in l1:
    for word in group:
        if word in words: 
            if word not in my_dict:
                my_dict[word] = [0,0]
            my_dict[word][0] += 1
for group in l2
    for word in group:
        if word in words:
            if word not in my_dict:
                my_dict[word] = [0,0]
            my_dict[word][1] += 1
```

Though if you are just wanting to know the words in common, perhaps sets could be an option as well, since you have the union operators in sets for easy viewing of all words in common, but sets eliminate duplicates so if the counts are necessary, then the set isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks Davy, i think i just couldn't visualize 'a list as a value', but it works perfectly. Sets aren't an option as you said, as i need the number of hits!

Comment: Absolutely. @Ajax1234 's itertools example is more efficient, but you can keep this dictionary counting as a tool in your back pocket if you find a situation where you can't use `chain` . Good luck!